# How to install MySQL Server so it doesn't "go away" after reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, installation, apt

### All Good:

Mysql server installed just fine by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

During installation I was prompted to choose a root password. After install I was able to log in to mysql monitor using this command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and when prompted I entered the password and logged in successfully.

### Problem:

When I reboot my server and then try to login to mysql monitor, upon entering the password I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

When I look in `/var/run/mysqld/` I do not see any file called `mysqld.sock`. Previously before the reboot there was a file by that name in that location. It was also highlighted red in my client shell program (mRemoteNG).

If I try to create that file by doing:

```
sudo touch mysqld.sock
```

It does get created but it isn't highlighted red, and when I try to login again, I get the same error as before.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql and mysql-server countless times and the same issue arises every time.

I also tried stropping and starting mysql service and that didn't make any difference.

### Note:

I am only prompted to choose a password during the very 1st install of mysql-server on a clean Ubuntu install. After that whenever I uninstall and reinstall it, it doesn't prompt me to choose a password, just says it has been installed successfully.

### Question:

How to properly install mysql-server so that it will always be there even after rebooting the server?

Answer (score 5):

The way to get `mysql-server` installed and running on Debian or Ubuntu is literally `apt-get install mysql-server`.

If that doesn't work you have another problem, best solved by going to the logs and trying to work out why it doesn't start - the problem is absolutely *not* how you installed it.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure it's configured to start up properly upon reboot.  This typically means running "update-rc.d mysqld defaults" (or something very similar).  update-rc.d will create symlinks from /etc/init.d to the startup script directories, e.g., /etc/rc3.d.

I don't know if mysqld starts off using Upstart on your version of Ubuntu.  There will be a similar process to get the mysqld start script into /etc/init in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the distro, you shouldn't need to manually create the socket file.

Use chkconfig (CentOS):

```
chkconfig --level 345 mysqld on
```

Or create a symlink to the run levels you want the service executed on:

```
# Mysql Startup
ln -s /etc/init.d/mysqld /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S85mysqld
ln -s /etc/init.d/mysqld /etc/rc.d/rc4.d/S85mysqld
ln -s /etc/init.d/mysqld /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S85mysqld

# MySQL clean shutdown
ln -s /etc/init.d/mysqld /etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K85mysqld
ln -s /etc/init.d/mysqld /etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K85mysqld
```

When you say you've tried starting/stoping the service and that didn't do in anything, do you mean that: It did nothing in terms of auto-starting after reboot, or that it did nothing in terms of starting the mysql service period?

EDIT: Just realized you tagged the post with Ubuntu, Checkout Ubuntu's upstart scripts if you are on 10.04+, seems like aptitude should have dropped one in for you upon installation.  Checkout the logs in /var/log/mysql(d) also if you think it's configured to autostart and is failing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the mysqld.sock file you created - the server will create that automatically, and having a file there may cause it not to start anymore.

Install it with apt-get install mysql-server (like you said).

Reboot.  If it's not running after the reboot, do "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start"

Check that it's running now.  If not, look in /var/log/mysql and /var/log/daemon.log for any error messages

To make it always start on boot, run "update-rc.d mysql defaults"